# how to use $().hide to hide buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that dynamically creates a button whose ID calls a value that will make it unique.

```
id='btnRemove_" + rowId + "'
```

Because it has an id that calls a value, how would I use the `hide()` method to hide this button on certain conditions?

```js
var createChildTableRowDeleteButton = function(rowId, title) {
  return $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger remove' id='btnRemove_" + rowId + "' title='" + title + "'>" +"<span class='delete glyphicon white glyphicon-remove'></span></button>").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
};
```

Comment: A dynamically constructed `id` is still an `id` like any other.  It won't somehow prevent you from performing operations on that element.  Where are you trying to use `hide()` and what didn't work?

Comment: I've tried using it in the context of $("#btnRemove_" + rowId + "").hide();  but not sure I have the correct syntax in terms of the single and double quotes. @David

Comment: *"not sure I have the correct syntax "* - Do you get any syntax errors?  The empty string at the end of the expression that generates the selector is unnecessary, but I see nothing wrong with the syntax.  Have you tried it?  Does it not work in some way?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach to take when appending dynamic content is to use delegated event handlers. This way you don't need to write ugly code to generate, maintain or validate dynamically `id` attributes. The pattern looks something like this:

```js
// function to create the button
let createChildTableRowDeleteButton = title => `<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" title="${title}">${title}<span class="delete glyphicon white glyphicon-remove"></span></button>`;

// delegated event handler to handle button click
$('table').on('click', '.remove', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
});

// call the function to create the button
$('td').append(createChildTableRowDeleteButton('foo bar'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have to have dynamically created ID's because there are more than one buttons. With the code I already have, would $("#btnRemove_" + rowId + "").hide();  work in my case?

Comment: `I have to have dynamically created ID's because there are more than one buttons` this is exactly why you ***shouldn't*** be using dynamic ids. Use a common class on all those elements and use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find related content within the event handlers - exactly as the example does above using `closest()`.